# How do I set up Custom email domain to be its own mailbox?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email

I’ve recently set up my own email domain to replace my ISP email as my main email address. This also includes setting it as my AppleID email address once I get this issue sorted.

I’ve hit a snag though when it comes to setting it up properly.

At the moment it’s acting like an alias for my iCloud email address and not its own independent email address.

There is only 2 options that I can see.

1. Have everything in one inbox.
2. Set up mail 'Rules' to push the mail for one of the accounts into a folder.

Option 1 is messy, disorganised and also if you use signatures, you have to be 100% on focus, because although the outgoing email address changes based on which email you're replying to, the signature doesn't.

Option 2, still untidy, but any mail that gets pushed to a folder through use of 'rules' does not trigger any notifications, show as app icon badges or appear in any mail widgets ie unread, today, all inboxes. So not really an inbox/mailbox.

I can set up ‘rules’ to move one of the email addresses to a different folder. However that is only a hack at best as any mail redirected to a folder, does not receive notifications, badges, or appear in any mail widgets showing unread mail. Screenshot attached showing what I mean. This also shows that the so called 'mailboxes' users can add are not in fact a mailbox and do not operate as a mailbox.

I'm hoping I'm missing something, but even Apple support weren't overly sure of themselves or clear when I was on the phone to them earlier. In all honesty nothing about this Custom Email Domains feels like an Apple Experience. It's messy and feels like it's in concept phase at best. It hasn't had much thought whatsoever put into it.

[image]